# How can I disable on hover marker animation in Highcharts 6.x?

Tags: highcharts

I recently upgraded to Highcharts 6, and noticed a marker animation that wasn't there before. I would like to disable it, and can't seem to do so. Before I raise it with Highcharts, I was wondering if I've done something wrong.

To be clear:

- I would like on hover styling (increased marker radius and halo)
- I do not want any animation on marker hover - either animating in, or animating out

To see the misbehaving markers, load [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goodforenergy/dqohbuo0/6/) and move your mouse over a point and away again. If you comment out the recent Highcharts import and instead use 4.2.5, you'll see the behaviour I'm after.

The only way I can see in the docs to disable on hover animation is to set the animation duration to 0. I tried to do this at three points in the configuration:

- [plotOptions.spline.marker.states.hover.animation.duration](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.marker.states.hover.animation.duration)
- [plotOptions.spline.states.hover.animation.duration](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.states.hover.animation.duration)
- [plotOptions.spline.states.hover.marker.states.hover.animation.duration](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.spline.states.hover.marker.states.hover.animation.duration)

Like so..

```
plotOptions: {
    spline: {
        marker: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    animation: {
                        duration: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 0
                },
                marker: {
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            animation: {
                                duration: 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But nothing worked. Help very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you manage to disable the marker animation without disabling animation for the rest of the chart?

Comment: @DanielLoiterton we ended up just living with it, I think - but I raised an [issue](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/7293) and there's a workaround listed there that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling `chart.animation` seems to resolve the problem. It disables overall animation for all chart updating but, as API states, it can be overridden for each individual API method as a function parameter.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation.html

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/sgz9dq8h/

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your quick response. I thought for a moment your fiddle wasn't working, but it looks like it's a highcharts bug. If you look at this screencast (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5an4xqgj0yfdimi/highcharts-bug.mov?dl=0) you'll see the bug is still there in your fiddle, but only on the first point, and it goes away on resize. Seems suspicious - I'll take it up with highcharts. Thanks!